# Django library: define custom settings

Tags: python, django, plugins, settings

I am working on a Django library, something released on Pypi as a plugable component. Some settings in this plugin should be customized by users, simply by setting values in `settings.py`. Currently I use this logic:

```
# config.py
import django.conf


class DefaultValues(object):

    SETTING_1 = []
    SETTING_2 = 42


class SettingsWrapper(object):
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        result = getattr(django.conf.settings, item, None)
        if result:
            return result
        return getattr(DefaultValues, item)


settings = SettingsWrapper()
```

And in my library, when I need to get the setting value, I do:

```
from mylib.config import settings

[...]
settings.SETTING_1
```

It works fine, but I feel I reinvent the wheel. The goal here is to get value first from `django.conf.settings` module (user settings), and if the value is not defined, retrieve it from `DefaultValues` class.

Recently, digging into Django code, I discovered the `django.conf` module, with the classes `LazySettings`, `BaseSettings` and `Settings`. In particular, the doc for `BaseSettings` say:

> Common logic for settings whether set by a **module** or by the user.

My question is: can I transform my module `conf` to use Django classes and perform the same work (maybe better) ?

Comment: There was a feature request for this and they shot it down. It's stupid because everyone needs it. Most people make a settings.py in their app and do FOO=getattr (settings, 'FOO', 'default')

Comment: There's no standard way. The simplest is probably, as mentioned by @kagronick, `FOO=getattr (settings, 'FOO', 'default')`. There's also `django-appconf`, which I think is relatively popular, but personally I think the benefits aren't worth the cost of adding an additional third-party module.